# How to add text to center the pie chart with nivo rocks for reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, charts, nivo-slider

I'm having trouble adding text to center the  pie chart, I'm using novio.rocks for my react project. Thanks
Demo https://nivo.rocks/pie

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add an extra div on top of the chart, centering its content using flexbox, I've created an example of this approach on codesandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/w27xwy0xlk
Don't forget to add `pointer-events: none` to preserve the chart's interactivity.

Comment: thanks, btw how to change tilt radialLabels, i want radialLabels  inclined 45 degrees
not 90 degrees in the pie chart ?